# for loop through php array

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Guys this is the complete code:

```
   $response = $this->db->select('DATE(`created_at`) as `day`')->select('MIN(`paid_amount`) as `min_amount`')->select('MAX(`paid_amount`) as `max_amount`')->get('orders');

$nation = array();
foreach ($response->result() as $row)
{
    print_r((array)$row);
    array_push($nation, (array)$row);
}
```

I got output for print_r shown below :

```
   Array
    (
        [day] => 2013-03-24
        [min_amount] => 2.00
        [max_amount] => 2.00
        [avg_amount] => 2.000000
        [total_revenue] => 2.00
        [total_orders] => 1
        [total_subscriptions] => 0
        [total_refunds] => 0
        [refunded_amount] => 1.00
    )
```

I used the below forloop but its not wrking. how to iterate through this array:

```
foreach($nation as $key=>$value)
{
      echo $key;
}
```

Comment: "It is not working" is not a valid PHP error message.

Comment: What output do you want ?

Comment: *how to iterate through this array* Just like you did is fine.

Comment: I am getting the output as 0

Comment: try `echo "key=$key, value=$value\n";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($nation as $key=>$value)
{
      echo $key." = ".$value;
      echo "<br />";
}
```

That should output:

```
 day = 2013-03-24
 min_amount = 2.00
 max_amount = 2.00
 avg_amount = 2.000000
 total_revenue = 2.00
 total_orders = 1
 total_subscriptions = 0
 total_refunds = 0
 refunded_amount = 1.00
```

If nothing is printed out, it means the array `$nation` is empty. You can also confirm this by

```
print_r($nation);
```

#### EDIT

After seeing your updated question, this should do the trick:

```
foreach($nation as $array)
{
   echo $array['day'];
   echo '<br />';
   echo $array['min_amount'];
   echo '<br />';
   .
   .
   .
    and so on
}
```

Comment: How is this an answer? All you changed is `echo $key;` to `echo $key." = ".$value; echo "<br/>";`.

Comment: That is not the answer. The part in the **EDIT** section is. I updated it after the OP posted more information

Comment: @asprin: for some reason the edit part didn't show until I did a complete refresh...

Comment: No worries..it happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how did you declare an array but see below:

```
$nation = array (
    'day' => 2013-03-24,
    'min_amount' => 2.00,
    'max_amount' => 2.00,
    'avg_amount' => 2.000000,
    'total_revenue' => 2.00,
    'total_orders' => 1,
    'total_subscriptions' => 0,
    'total_refunds' => 0,
    'refunded_amount' => 1.00,
);

foreach ($nation as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array looks like it's printed out already.

Try `var_dump($nation);` and see what appears - your `$nation` may not be an array or it's not set.

It should look something like this:

```
$nation = array (
    'day'                  => 2013-03-24,
    'min_amount'           => 2.00,
    'max_amount'           => 2.00,
    'avg_amount'           => 2.000000,
    'total_revenue'        => 2.00,
    'total_orders'         => 1,
    'total_subscriptions'  => 0,
    'total_refunds'        => 0,
    'refunded_amount'      => 1.00
);
```

To print it out:

```
foreach($nation as $key => $value){
    echo $key.' -> '.$value.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using array_push() to enter the rows into $nation. Each row will be numbered from 0 , 1, 2 etc. If you have only just 1 row, you will only have item `0`. That is the `0` you are seeing.

You actually need to do this:

```
foreach($nation as $row) // getting the rows you entered with array_push(). In your case now it's just 1.
{
    foreach($row as $key=>$value) // getting the fields in each row
    {
        echo $key; // getting the field name. (Use $value if you want the field data.)
    }
}
```